# What is the most optimal way to find all duplicates or more?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a query which is going to find all rows with 2 or more same names. I wrote it as follows:

```
SELECT name 
FROM (
      SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count 
      FROM partner.propertie 
      GROUP BY name) as t 
WHERE t.count > 1;
```

But I'm not sure if it's an optimal way to do that. I have quite large table...

Comment: you could try something like this "select name, count(*) as count from partner.propertie group by name having count(*) > 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING` is what you want:

```
SELECT name 
FROM partner.propertie 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: This is a fine answer, but I don't think it will perform any better than the OP's original query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select * from (
  SELECT name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name asc) AS Row
  FROM partner.propertie 
) dups
where 
dups.Row > 1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1435c/2)**